# Forms.ComboBox color

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I want to change the color of a System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox in C#.  I **don't** mean `BackColor` or `ForeColor` which control the color once I click on the combo box and it presents the dropdown list.  Instead I want to change the color of the control itself.

Comment: You could make a custom ComboBox, let it inherit from the ComboBox class: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbI9cmfPQ8Q tutorial...

Comment: You must be talking about DropDownStyle = DropDownList.  No, colors are determined by the visual style theme that the user selected.  Creating your own visual style is not supported by winforms.  Plenty of skinning libraries around, check component vendors like DevExpress and Telerik.